# Google Play Game Services: strange sign in behavior

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

Recently I've added Google Play Game Services support in my app (added BaseGameActivity and GameHelper), and it sign-in and sign-out workflow worked fine. In my graphics thread I send message to main activity handler, it calls beginUserInitiatedSignIn or signOut. When identification process completes Game Helper calls onSignInFailed or onSignInSucceeded of my activity and I can check isSignedIn (true if onSignInSucceeded was called).

But today I've found that it behaves strange now. Sadly that I did not backup last working version, but the essense code is the same.

If I ask app to sign in it shows google services sign-in dialog (I have 2 accounts on my device). I choose an account, press ok, it returns to my app but neither onSignInSucceeded nor onSignInFailed is called (previously if I canceled this dialog I saw "unknown error" message).  When I try to sign in in the second time it launches a rotating circle and waits endlessly. If I tap on screen it aborts waiting and returns to my view.

ALTHOUGH if I close the app and launch it once again, it signs in on launch successfully, call onSignSucceded and stay connected when I check in runtime. It says:

```
onCreate: creating GamesClient
onStart.
onStart: connecting clients.
Connecting GamesClient.
onConnected: connected! client=1
All clients now connected. Sign-in successful.
All requested clients connected. Sign-in succeeded!
```

If I sign out and then try to sign in again, it shows accounts dialog and writes:

```
isGooglePlayServicesAvailable returned 0
beginUserInitiatedSignIn: starting new sign-in flow.
Connecting GamesClient.
onConnectionFailed: result 4
onConnectionFailed: since user initiated sign-in, trying to resolve problem.
resolveConnectionResult: trying to resolve result: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{41f8a610: android.os.BinderProxy@41f8a5b0}}
result has resolution. Starting it.
```

When I choose an account it returns to my activity and neither onSignInSucceeded nor onSignInFailed is called. If I check in runtime I see that app is not connected to google services.
When I try to sign in again it shows forever rotating circle and says:

```
isGooglePlayServicesAvailable returned 0
beginUserInitiatedSignIn: continuing pending sign-in flow.
resolveConnectionResult: trying to resolve result: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{41f8a610: android.os.BinderProxy@41f8a5b0}}
result has resolution. Starting it.
```

When I tap the screen, circle is aborted without calls to onSignInSucceeded nor onSignInFailed and so on.

I can't imagine what went wrong. Handler is created on main thread. I have Google example, and it signs in and signs out without any problem, just like my app did. Can somebody tell what can be wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you need to share some code!

Comment: Actually I don't know what code to share... Everything is as always. My activity is descedant of BaseGameActivity from Google. I call on main thread these two methods (beginUserInitiatedSignIn or signOut) and expect callbacks onSignInSucceeded or onSignInFailed. I thought if someone faced with similar symptoms they can suggest what's wrong. Maybe something happened to server setup. But it worked before...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It took 2 days to find a silly mistake. When you extend BaseGameActivity make sure you call all its methods in your activity methods (if you override them), for example:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 ....
 <our code here>
}
```

BaseGameActivity calls its aggregated mHelper's methods which do all the magic.

Comment: Wow this was the exact solution I needed.  I added onActivityResult but tested it before adding the code I needed (including super.onActivityResult).  Thanks for posting your solution!!!

Comment: You're a life saver ! I'll give you +100 reputation in 23 hours !

Comment: Since this moment in life I moved to mercurial. If only I commit every day - I could see what was changed, but with svn I had to beware and work in offline (I've gone through svn branch merge nightmare couple of times :) )

Comment: YOU. ARE. DA. MAN. THANK YOU!

Comment: Nice find! I'm having the exact same problem, I forgot to call `super()` from `onActivityResult()`. Thanks for posting your solution, it saved me a lot of time.