# Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza

Tags: android, google-maps

Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza

Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.

In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)

Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.

Ensure that the following Android Key exists:

API Key:

Android Application (;): FD:9E:49:CD:63:;com.xxx.xxx

Comment: I have checked api key many times.All seems to be perfect.

Comment: seems like your issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29276292/android-maps-api-exception/29276586#29276586

Comment: facing the same problem right now

Answer (score 1):

Well, if anyone is still wondering...I had the same issue and finally figured it out. AppOpsManager was added in **API level 19**. Make sure your **targetSdkVersion** in your AndroidManifest.xml is the right one.

Comment: my targetSdkVersion is 22 but still its giving the error