# Google Play Game Services Sign In callback

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services, google-play-games

I try to setup google play game service in my cocos2d-x game. I use for this BaseGameActivity.java and GameHelper.java files, so my main class is inherited from BaseGameActivity. 
When I call mHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn() it show google play activity, and then hide it. But callbacks (onSignInSucceeded and onSignInFailed) not called. When I try call mHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn() again it send me massage "GameHelper WARNING: beginUserInitiatedSignIn() called when already connecting...".

```
!!! GameHelper WARNING: beginUserInitiatedSignIn() called when already connecting. Be patient! You can only call this method after you get an onSignInSucceeded() or onSignInFailed() callback. Suggestion: disable the sign-in button on startup and also when it's clicked, and re-enable when you get the callback.
```

Comment: Are you certain that you've set up the GameHelper by providing your GameHelperListener into `mHelper.setup(listener)`?

Comment: Maybe it can help me?
BaseGameActivity(4397): GameHelper: onConnectionFailed
BaseGameActivity(4397): GameHelper: Connection failure:
BaseGameActivity(4397): GameHelper:    - code: SIGN_IN_REQUIRED(4)
BaseGameActivity(4397): GameHelper:    - resolvable: true
BaseGameActivity(4397): GameHelper:    - details: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{419d9b58: android.os.BinderProxy@41a08768}}
BaseGameActivity(4397): GameHelper: onConnectionFailed: since user initiated sign-in, resolving problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google Play Game Services: strange sign in behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16802775/google-play-game-services-strange-sign-in-behavior?rq=1)

`super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);`

Comment: Ah, yes, that makes sense. BaseGameActivity takes care of handling the result, so if you override it without passing unhandled requestCodes into the super, you'll effectively break the flow.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is also caused because of Game services are in testing mode (and not published), So add your user to tester.

After publishing app Developer needs to add release SHA1 (release management >> app signing, if you selected google signing apps while publishing) to app credentials under https://console.developers.google.com/

**Google app signing SHA1 should be used not what you generate from local PC**<< This is what took my two days straight

Hope this helps someone